# How to get Arista Transcoder working

Tags: python, dependencies, ffmpeg, transcode, arista-transcoder

[Arista Transcoder](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/arista) is a video converter for Linux that is the only one in existence that makes videos half the file size with no quality loss. When I use FFMPEG or ANY other converter on the same files, they end up even larger than the original... this program is a godsend.

But it's 10 years old now and doesn't work! When I download and compile from source (python) it just keeps telling me `import error, no module named gobject`.

People online say do `pip install gobject`, which I did, but the error persists. So I removed the line completely. Then it says the very next module doesn't exist. They all don't exist. I guess the package is too old and none of the dependencies are in the same place anymore in a modern Ubuntu install.

Please, anyone, how can we get this miracle software working again?

Comment: There are generally two possible answers: You can resurrect the project, fork the code, and update it. Or you can spin up a virtual environment running a 10-year-old OS to run this 10-year old software.

Comment: What are the steps to update the code? I would like to do that, but I don't know where to start